# Multiply all combinations of rows of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices A(3X4) and B(3X4). I would like to calculate a new matrix (3X3X4) that has as row elements the element-wise multiplication of each row of A with each row of B. I guess it's like a multi-dimensional outer product. Any way to do this in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: Do you mean (3X3X4) or (3X4X3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [3, 2, 1]))
```

or possibly

```
permute(bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [3,2,1])), [1,3,2])
```

Comment: Remove the "@" though at the start. Couldn't edit it this time :)

Comment: @LuisMendo The result would make lesser sense then though.

Comment: @Divakar Why? It would be: (row of A, row of B, common column). Makes more sense to me than the current (row of A, common column, row of B)

Comment: @LuisMendo Because you are doing row-wise multiplication, so a natural  thing would be to store them in rows of the 2D sections of the final 3D. In MATLAB, the way 3D output appears would make sense too, as one won't have to scroll all the way upto the last dimension of the 3D data to see the first row multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Z=[]

for i=1:3
for j=1:3
Z=[Z;A(i,:).*B(i,:)];
end
end

Z=reshape(Z(:),[3,3,4]);
```

Now Z has the result you need